# How do I allow people to upload videos and then others watch them without them being able to download?

Tags: video, streaming

I'd like to allow users to upload videos and then have other users view when they have done task that allows them to.

EDIT: The purpose of the site is video tutorials. If the person is able to pass the test for the first video then they can watch the second video in the series. Basically limiting what videos they are able to watch. What I really don't want is direct download.

Comment: Upload onto your site? More info is needed I believe.

Comment: can you explain without being able to download part? A video is needed to be downloaded in background by browser without user noticing partially or fully to be viewed if thats what you mean (Temporary internet files). you can't do such thing, you can hack it maybe by slicing the video to small pieces. If you meant banning downloaders like Orbit or such third party programs to copy the content, not really sure whats the best way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer is you can't.**  If they can watch the video, they are downloading it.  Even if you use a flash viewer, they are still downloading it.

Netflix and others get around this limitation by putting DRM in their streamed movies that only their (silverlight) players can unlock.  You can do all kinds of tricks, but firebug and chrome dev tools will allow me to easily defeat any tricks you might have.

Take for instance the spaceball.gif that flickr uses to keep you for right-click saving an image from their site.  All you have to do is pop open the dev tools, and save the image from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can bet YouTube would do this, but they merely succeeded making it inconvenient.